# Grandparent to Child mapping using Hibernate and JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I use Spring, Hibernate and JPA.
(I will mention that this is a dropwizard application and not springboot, although I don't think it should have any affect...)

Storage: MySql.

There's no usage with foreign key in the database.

#### Note:

As mentioned in one of the comments below -
I totally agree that saving the grandparent id within the child table isn't ideal, and traversing child -> parent -> grandparent is a better practice. Specifically for this question please consider this as a given situation (kind of a legacy code I can't change now...)

I have the following JPA entities:
(names have been changed)

**The GrandParent:**

```
@Entity
public class GrandParent {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "int unsigned not null")
    private Long id;

    //... some other fields... getters and setters

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private Set<Parent> parents;

    public void addParent(Parent parent) {
        if (this.parents == null) {
            this.parents = new HashSet<>();
        }
        this.parents.add(parent);
        parent.setGrandParent(this);
    }

    public void removeParent(Parent parent) {
        this.parents.remove(parent);
        parent.setGrandParent(null);
    }

}
```

**The Parent:**

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "int unsigned")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "grand_parent_id", referencedColumnName = "id", columnDefinition = "int unsigned")
    private GrandParent grandParent;
   
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private Set<Child> children;

    // other fields, getters and setters

    public void addChild(Child child) {
        if (this.fields == null) {
            this.fields = new HashSet<>();
        }
        this.children.add(child);
        child.setParent(this);
    }

    public void removeChild(Child child) {
        this.children.remove(child);
        child.setParent(null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Parent )) return false;
        return id != null && id.equals(((Parent) o).getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getClass().hashCode();
    }

}
```

**The Child:**

```
@Entity
public class Child {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "int unsigned")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "grand_parent_id", columnDefinition = "int unsigned")
    private GrandParent grandParent;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", columnDefinition = "int unsigned")
    private Parent parent;

    // other fields, getters and setters


}
```

I create a GrandParent instant in the following manner (I'm mentioning just the relevant fields...):

```
Child child = Child.builder()
                .someField("1")
                .someOtherField(1)
                .build();

Parent parent = Parent.builder()
                .someField("1")
                .someOtherField(1)
                .build();
        parent.addChild(child);
        
GrandParent grandParent = GrandParent.builder()
                .someField("1")
                .someOtherField(1)
                .build();
        grandParent.addParent(parent);
```

In My Repository I save GrandParent entity using:

```
hibernateSession.save(grandParent);
```

Indeed all rows stored successfully, Yet the child.grand_parent_id remains Null.

What’s wrong, and how can it be solved?

**For better visibility I'm adding this update** (refer to @MauricioBuffon comment below)

I tried to set the `GrandParent` explicitly in the `Child` by editing the `addChild` method in `Parent` Entity:

```
public void addChild(Child child) { 
        if (this.children == null) {             
             this.children = new HashSet<>();         
        }         
        this.children.add(child);         
        child.setParent(this);
        //let's try...
        child.setGrandParent(getGrandParent());
     }
```

Still the Child.grand_parent_id = Null.

So question remains:

What’s wrong, and how can it be solved?

Comment: While it may not directly solve your problem i'd like to ask: Is having the direct link from Child to Grandparent really necessary? Isn't having a link to the parent and them from there to the grandparent enough to model the relation? When doing queries you might have to do an extra join, but at least the relation wouldn't be saved twice redundantly in the database.

Comment: Are you setting the `grandParent` member during the `Child` entity creation? Could you please share this part of the code?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS - I couldn't agree more, yet that's the situation I'm facing. I did edit my question with this clarification, thanks

Comment: @MauricioBuffon - Actually no, I didn't set the `grandParent` member explicitly in the `Child` - This should be handled by Hibernate no? I edited the question with the way I'm creating the entities. Thanks

Comment: @mesh Well, how should Hibernate know how to derive that value then? Note that, in your code, the `@OneToOne` relationship is unidirectional.

Comment: @MauricioBuffon I have updated the `addChild` method in Parent like this:  `public void addChild(Child child) {
        if (this.children == null) {
            this.children = new HashSet<>();
        }
        this.children.add(child);
        child.setParent(this);
        //let's try...
        child.setGrandParent(getParent());
    }` I guess that's what you meant - Still child.grand_parent_id is Null.

Comment: @mesh Yes, that's what I meant. The `Child#setParent` method isn't a problem (because the Child - Parent relationship is bidirectional; both entities map the relation). But the `Child#setGrandParent` method is necessary to let Hibernate know how to populate the `grand_parent_id` column in `child` table.

Comment: @MauricioBuffon First apologies, this should be `child.setGrandParent(getGrandParent())` I fixed it in the question. Still - it doesn't seem to solve the problem - **child.grand_parent_id is still NULL**

Comment: @mesh Yeah, but note the order in your code: 1) create the child 2) create the parent 3) add the child to parent 3.1) set the grandParent of the child (which is null at this point) 4) create the grandParent 5) add the parent to grandParent. You have to assure that when you call `Child#setGrandParent` the object is not null.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253690/discussion-between-mesh-and-mauricio-buffon).

Answer (score 1):

Root cause - I haven't set the grandParent explicitly on the child.
Having a one to one unidirectional relation between those entities, this is the way to go.

Credits to @MauricioBuffon

```
public void addParent(Parent parent) {
        if (this.parents == null) {
            this.parents = new HashSet<>();
        }
        this.parents.add(parent);
        parent.setGrandParent(this);
        parent.getChildren().stream().forEach(child -> child.setGrandParent(this));
    }
```